# Magento - Search Results

Tags: php, magento

If my search criteria is configured for 'Full Text' it doesn't seem to bring back any products where the SKU is under 4 characters, even though the minimal query length is set to 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609935/mysql-full-text-indexing-limitations#answer-610301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's to do with MySQL Full text search being set to 4 chars.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you done an index rebuild since changing the min word length?

```
REPAIR TABLE table_name QUICK;
```